How to make a client connection to Windows DCOM?
I'm new to DCOM.
I need to make a DCOM connection from one Windows server to another and execute a method on one of the Microsoft-exposed services.
How do I get started? Is there a basic example of making a connection in C++, C#, Go, or another language?
Assume I'm logged in as an Active Directory admin, and both servers are domain-joined.

Finding COM/DCOM examples is not that easy, because MSoft fellows think that it is an internal low level product, and that application developpers should not ge beyond .NET. I can just remember this oold piece of code on CodeProject. Although it is clearly out of date, it should be enough to find some starting point. You will then find more up to date information in Microsoft COM documentation. Good luck...
